# Designing own robot for Gazebo simulation?

Tags: quadcopter, ros, gazebo

For my project I am trying to model and control a quadrotor with actuating arms. As I don't have a physical model with me, I want to simulate and control the robot using ROS and Gazebo.

At the moment I have created a CAD design (servos are used to rotate the arms). I have read about URDF and know that I can define stuff such as sensors, velocity, inertia etc. The question here is as to how I can link the urdf with my cad model. How can I make the propellers and servos move to make the robot fly?

Comment: You can search for an exporter from your CAD model to URDF, for example for solidworks there is an  [add-on](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter)

Comment: Have you tried searching for drone urdf models? Maybe they can provide insight by reverse engineering them, and checking up on how they designed and implemented the propellers.

Answer (score 2):

Modelling a quadcopter is a complex process. I would highly recommend starting with an existing model which is fully operational and then modifying it or extending it to match your design. You're going to need a lot more components than just converting your CAD model to URDF to get the simulation going.

There's a large variety of open source examples you can start with in the PX4 project. I recommend checking out the [User Guide](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/simulation/gazebo.html) or the [Developer Guide](https://dev.px4.io/v1.10_noredirect/en/simulation/gazebo.html) as starting points.